# Multiple Screens | Python Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a program with multiple screens. I have it working where if I click the buttons in the main screen it does switch screens, but once in the screen and I try to click the other button to go back to the main screen it doesn't work. How would I fix that so it does go back to the main screen?

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import font
from tkinter import messagebox

win = tk.Tk()
# Screen
screen = tk.Tk()
screen.title('Main Menu')
screen.geometry('600x400')

# Font
style1 = font.Font(size=25)
style2 = font.Font(size=20)

## Direction Screen || Text, Back Button (Returns to main Screen)
class how_to_play(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        win.title('How To Play')
        win.geometry('600x400')
        ttk.Label(self, text = 'Game Insturctions').pack()
        ttk.Label(self, text = 'another label').pack()
        ttk.Button(self, text = 'Exit', command = main_menu).pack()

# Game Screen || Hang Man, Letter/Word Input, Trys left, Incorrt Answers, Back Button (Returns to Main Screen)
def game():
    game = tk.Toplevel()
    game.title('Hang Man')
    game.geometry('600x400')
    ttk.Label(game, text = 'Hang Man').pack()
    ttk.Button(game, text = 'Exit', command = main_menu).pack()
    ttk.Label(game, text = 'another label').pack(expand = True)
    
# Main Menu Screen
def main_menu():
    menu = tk.Toplevel()
    menu.title('Main Menu')
    menu.geometry('600x400')
    ttk.Label(screen, text = 'Main Menu').pack()
    button1 = ttk.Button(screen, text = 'How To Play', command = how_to_play)
    button1.pack(expand = True)

    button2 = ttk.Button(screen, text = 'Play', command = game)
    button2.pack(expand = True)
    
# run 
main_menu()
screen.mainloop()
```

[image: Main Screen]
[image: How to Play]
[image: Should be back to the Main Screen, but it isnt]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are getting a little confused with all the `Toplevel`. Do you really want to have seperate windows?

If so then create a class for `game` in the same way as `how_to_play`. This way you can instanciate both from the buttons in the main window (main menu). To return simply `destroy()` the Toplevel and only the main window remains:

**Multi window solution:**

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Main Menu')
        self.geometry('600x400')
        ttk.Label(self, text='Main Menu').pack()
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text='How To Play', command=self.InstrScreen)
        button1.pack(expand=True)
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text='Play', command=self.GameScreen)
        button2.pack(expand=True)

    # Direction Screen as Toplevel
    class InstrScreen(tk.Toplevel):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.title('How To Play')
            self.geometry('600x400')
            ttk.Label(self, text='Game Insturctions').pack()
            ttk.Label(self, text='another label').pack()
            ttk.Button(self, text='Exit', command=self.destroy).pack()

    # Game Screen as Toplevel
    class GameScreen(tk.Toplevel):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.title('Hang Man')
            self.geometry('600x400')
            ttk.Label(self, text='Hang Man').pack()
            ttk.Button(self, text='Exit', command=self.destroy).pack()
            ttk.Label(self, text='another label').pack(expand=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # instanciate App and run it
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

---

**Single window solution:**

But if you actually want only the contents to change without having multiple windows popping open, you have to create seperate frames and `pack()` and `pack_forget()` them depending on what you want to show:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from functools import partial


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Main Menu')
        self.geometry('600x400')
        # initialize main menu as frame
        self.main_menu_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        ttk.Label(self.main_menu_frame, text='Main Menu').pack()
        button1 = ttk.Button(self.main_menu_frame, text='How To Play', command=self.show_how_to_play)
        button1.pack(expand=True)
        button2 = ttk.Button(self.main_menu_frame, text='Play', command=self.init_game)
        button2.pack(expand=True)
        # Direction Screen as frame
        self.instructions_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        ttk.Label(self.instructions_frame, text='Game Insturctions').pack()
        ttk.Label(self.instructions_frame, text='another label').pack()
        ttk.Button(self.instructions_frame, text='Exit',
                   command=partial(self.back_to_main_menu, self.instructions_frame)).pack()
        # Game Screen as frame
        self.game_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        ttk.Label(self.game_frame, text='Hang Man').pack()
        ttk.Button(self.game_frame, text='Exit', command=partial(self.back_to_main_menu, self.game_frame)).pack()
        ttk.Label(self.game_frame, text='another label').pack(expand=True)
        # only pack menu to start with
        self.main_menu_frame.pack()

    # function to unload the menu frame, change the window title and load instructions frame
    def show_how_to_play(self):
        self.main_menu_frame.pack_forget()
        self.title('How To Play')
        self.instructions_frame.pack()

    # function to unload the menu frame, change the window title and load game frame
    def init_game(self):
        self.main_menu_frame.pack_forget()
        self.title('Hang Man')
        self.game_frame.pack()

    # function to unload either the instructions or game frame, change the window title and load menu frame
    # since it is triggeret by both the button in game and instructions frame the button has to pass the frame to unload
    def back_to_main_menu(self, from_where):
        from_where.pack_forget()
        self.title('Main Menu')
        self.main_menu_frame.pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # instanciate App and run it
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think I would instead want the contents to change on screen rather than different windows. How would I do that?

Comment: Its what I show in the code of my answer!

Comment: My bad! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, hope it helps!

Comment: I edited my answer to show both the `Toplevel` and the *switching single window content*  solution with code

Comment: I see you have used my code in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77240976/changing-the-properties-of-buttons-and-labels-using-tkinter-ttk). May I ask you to accept it then?

Comment: Yes! I will. I didn't know That I could do that!